# Will created process from multiprocessing command, will run on same kubernetes node?

Tags: python, kubernetes

Kubernetes support `load-balancing`.

Let's take a simple senario:

- Process runs on one node
- That process creates multiple processes
- Do all new processes will run on same Kubernetes node ? or on multiple nodes (while supporting load-balancing ? )

simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

In the example above, we are creating 3 processes.

- Do all the 3 processes run on same k8s node ? or it may be that 2 processes run on one node and the third process will run on the third node ?

Comment: All processes will run on the same kubernetes node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't quite understand docker yet. Since a container contains this application, all of the memory/executions will be done in this container only, with or without K8s.

K8s only serves as a docker orchestrator for multiple containers, which normally, there should not be any communication at all between containers.

So the answer is all of the processes it created in the same node will be executed on that particular node only.